# Command-not-found not triggered for 'crash' in ZSH without reason

Tags: zsh, crash, command-not-found

I just typed `crash` in my ZSH (from oh-my-zsh if that matters) and I got peculiar answer:

`zsh: permission denied: crash`

instead of the usual command-not-found behaviour expected (since I have that plugin installed).

Please help me understand why or point me in where I can debug this. Other words don't trigger any such message, it's the usual command not found behaviour. `type crash` states `crash not found`.

```
➜  ~ crash
zsh: permission denied: crash
➜  ~ type crash
crash not found
➜  ~ type crashaa
crashaa not found
➜  ~ type crsdadsadsa
crsdadsadsa not found
➜  ~ ieusrferw
zsh: command not found: ieusrferw
➜  ~ crashaa
zsh: command not found: crashaa
➜  ~ crash
zsh: permission denied: crash
```

Curiosity got the best of me: `sudo crash` reports `sudo: crash: command not found`. :P

Thank you @Gilles and @StéphaneChavelaz, for prompt hints:

1. `set -x` gave a lot of output, but core didn't change, right after command being executed there's no permission. I'll copy/paste output once I understand it a bit more :-)
2. No, I don't have the `crash` directory, I even created a temp `aaa` dir and repeated things there, no change. Nor do I remember setting `crash` on path. Also, sudo doesn't help, well, it shows "no such command".

Comment: Run `set -x` to see what's going on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can reproduce it if I create a directory called `crash` in any of the directories in `$path`:

```
$ mkdir -p ~/bin/crash
$ path+=(~/bin)
$ crash
zsh: permission denied: crash
$ type crasn
crasn not found
```

The `permission denied` would be because `zsh` tries to execute that directory (and there's no other `crash` potential command to look  for in the rest of `$path`). Now that `type` doesn't report that directory when `zsh` tries to execute it when you enter `crash` could be seen as a bug.

Try `ls -ld -- $^path/crash(N/)` to confirm.

`dash`, `tcsh` (with `which`) and `fish` have the same problem. `ksh93` and `mksh` have a similar inconsistency, but at least their error message is more helpful:

```
$ ksh -c crash
ksh: crash: cannot execute [Is a directory]
$ ksh -c 'type crash'
ksh: whence: crash: not found
```

Comment: Precisely what it was. <bows deeply> Nice touch with regexing the $path shell var without error messages for non-existing dirs `(N/)`. I learned something nice, thank you. Another nice touch is extending the answer with other shells and commands. Unfortunately I can only upvote once! :( Thank you again!